# Link stylesheet from a parent folder

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following folder setup:

```
Main
    css
        stylesheet.css
    sub
        example
            index.php
    index.php
```

How do I link `stylesheet.css` for the `index.php` file in `example`?

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">`

This only works for `index.php` in the Main section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go two directories back like this: `../../`

`../` is used to fill the relative path structure.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: You would need to travel two directory back to get the `stylesheet.css`